# How to send UTF-8 encoded string through QTcpSocket in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I am able to send a string through a QTcpsocket. But,by default, Qt sends the string in UTF-16 encoded format. I want this to be sent in UTF-8 encoded format.
Is there a setting in Qt for this?

Comment: `QString::toUtf8`?

Comment: Presumably it just sends whatever you give it. Currently you're giving it a UTF-16 string. So give it a UTF-8 string instead. Disclaimer: I know very little about Qt :D

Comment: How do you currently send the QString over QTcpSocket?

Answer (score 0):

```
QString::toUtf8
```

solved the issue.